# html5 canvas percentage loading . any way to remove long values after point. it looks ugly

Tags: html, createjs

percentage loading shows something like **76.3547435%**. i want only the **76%**

```
progress.graphics.drawRect(115,112,400*(event.loaded / event.total),40);
txt.text = ("Loading " + 100*(event.loaded / event.total) + "%");
```

i checked it by divide **1024** . but it does not work

```
txt.text = ("Loading " + 100*(event.loaded / event.total) + "%")/1024;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) to remove the digits after the decimal.

```
txt.text = ("Loading " + Math.round(100*(event.loaded / event.total)) + "%");
```